# How to verify order of mocked views in custom wizard object

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, moq

I have a WPF MVVM application where I needed to create a custom Wizard-type containing object that controls the flow of various views. The Wizard contains a private internal list of Types that are later created into actual items, and has methods that manipulate which view you're on.

The Wizard works pretty great; it's now time to unit test it to make sure that the views are in the appropriate order.

The Wizard has an Initialize call that specifies its order of views. NextStep and PreviousStep are used to change which view you're currently on (they really just update an index and raise the property changed event), and outside object access the current view via a CurrentStep property that delivers the view. It uses a StructureMap IContainer to be able to instantiate those views.

```
public class WizardExample
{
    private IList<Type> _steps = new List<Type>();
    private int _currentStepIndex = 0;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _steps.Add(typeof(FirstStepView));
        _steps.Add(typeof(SecondStepView));
        _steps.Add(typeof(ThirdStepView));
    }

    public UserControl CurrentStep
    {
        get
        {
            Type currentStep = _steps[_currentStepIndex];
            return IOCContainer.GetInstance(currentStep) as UserControl;
        }
    }

    public IContainer IOCContainer { get; set; }

    public void NextStep()
    {
        if(_currentStepIndex < _steps.Count - 1)
        {
            ++_currentStepIndex;
        }
    }

    public void PreviousStep()
    {
        if(_currentStepIndex > 0)
        {
            --_currentStepIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

The tests I would like to perform would be something like this (I'm using Moq and MSTest):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestFirstPageType()
{
    Wizard testWizard = new Wizard();
    Mock<FirstStepView> mockFirstStepView = new Mock<FirstStepView>();
    mockFirstStepView.SetupAllProperties();

    Mock<IContainer> mockContainer = new Mock<IContainer>();
    mockContainer.Setup(c => c.GetInstance<FirstStepView>()).Returns(mockFirstStepView.Object);

    testWizard.IOCContainer = mockContainer.Object;
    testWizard.Initialize();

    FirstStepView testView = testWizard.CurrentStep as FirstStepView;
    Assert.IsTrue(testView != null);
}
```

However, when I go to execute this test, I get the following error:

> 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Expcetion: The
>   component 'Castle.Proxies.FirstStepViewProxy' does not have a resource
>   identified by the URI
>   '/MyDll;component/wizard/views/firststepview.xaml'

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was attempting to mock the views when I didn't need to. I've altered my test code to be this, and now my tests run fine.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestFirstPageType()
{
    Wizard testWizard = new Wizard();

    Mock<IContainer> mockContainer = new Mock<IContainer>();
    mockContainer.Setup(c => c.GetInstance<FirstStepView>()).Returns(new FirstStepView());

    testWizard.IOCContainer = mockContainer.Object;
    testWizard.Initialize();

    FirstStepView testView = testWizard.CurrentStep as FirstStepView;
    Assert.IsTrue(testView != null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the example, your setup

```
mockContainer.Setup(c => c.GetInstance<FirstStepView>()).Returns(mockFirstStepView.Object);
```

and what is called in your code

```
return IOCContainer.GetInstance(currentStep) as UserControl;
```

is different.

Your setup needs to match what intend to use in the test.

```
mockContainer.Setup(c => c.GetInstance(typeof(FirstStepView)).Returns(mockFirstStepView.Object);
```

Comment: While you are absolutely right that my test and what I call need to match, this did not solve the issue at hand. Making the correct setup call did not resolve the error.

Comment: Your views may be dependent on something that is only available in the resource dictionary at run time. It looks like it is trying to retrieve a XAML file which it cannot find. the resource dictionary is populated by the framework at start up which is probably not being done in the unit test